# MSI Laptop wont recognize any other OS installation

Tags: bios, uefi, efi

My MSI GF63 thin just wont recognizes any other installation Ubuntu/Solus/Arch as there BOOT path wont be in bios, is there any chance of bios being hardcoded to ignore any other OSs other than windows,[I can boot from live usb]

Comment: Any other OS than what? What have you done that makes you think your laptop ought to boot to a different OS? Have you followed any guides for dual- or multi-boot setup? Please clearly state what you've done, what you've tried, and what you want or expect to happen, adding all of this to the original post (not as comments).

Comment: @music2myear i just erased my ssd and tried to install different linux distros(not in dual boot), installation went just fine but none of them were able boot without live usb inserted, removing usb gives some bios screen which clearly means nothing to boot from

Answer (score 0):

On some Windows PC's on which I've tried to install Linux, the only consistent way I've found to force the machine to boot an alternative OS is to first **copy** and then to rename the original default boot loader, e.g. *bootmgfw.efi* to *win-bootmgfw.efi*, and to rename the grub or shim64 bootloader to that name, *bootmgfw.efi*.

The images below shows how to access the boot .efi files Windows [*bcdedit.exe*](https://www.itechguides.com/windows-boot-manager-how-to-edit-bootmgr-and-fix-boot-errors-in-windows-10/)

[image: Using bcdedit.exe]

and using a third-party GUI tool, [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) (those shown are for Linux).

[image: Boot EFI files]

**N.B.:** The reason to copy the original file, and better yet, *image the entire disk*, is to allow recovery to the original boot order if there are issues, or if you later wish to revert to the old OS.

Comment: im not trying to dual boot here, i just completely erased my ssd and installed ubuntu but it just wont boot without usb

Comment: As stated, renaming the grub64.efi (or shim64.efi) file to that of the original Windows boot manager. Thus, even if the BIOS were hard-coded to look for that file, it will open the Linux boot manager. This works either as single Linux boot or dual booting.